# Is it safe to upload pictures to a database through a site hosted on firebase?

Tags: database, firebase, security, hosting

I am working on a project that I intend to host using Firebase. It will have a database incorporated in it which will have pictures and mp3 files as entries.

I have a couple of questions regarding this project:

1. Will there be any concerns I should look into in terms of the security?
2. Would storing mp3 files in the database pose an issue?

Edit:
Thank you for replying. I will look into Storage for storing my mp3 files. As for the first question, I will be uploading pictures and audios and was concerned if those will be secure or like hacked and misused. Would I need to get a SSL certificate to prevent that?

Comment: 1) This very much depends on your definition of "secure" and of "issue", which makes it hard to help with. If you have a specific security concern or issue in mind, I suggest editing your question (there's a link right under it) to explain that. 2) I would recommend storing files in [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage), and not in the JSON or Document database.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, one should not upload pictures that has some value or could be worth if stolen ss a default Firebase database has no security, it's the development team's responsibility to correctly secure the database prior to it storing real data.

In Google Firebase, this is done by requiring authentication and implementing rule-based authorization for each database table. The configuration and security controls for any sensitive data also need to be checked using vulnerability scanners and pen test tools to verify that they have been implemented effectively. Clearly, there are plenty of projects that fail to implement these critical stages before releasing their applications.

Coming on the mp3 part, so yes it could be uploaded but firebase gives us a daily limit of free data usage that is 1GiB/day also there are other few things which firebase gives in the free tier.

[image]

So if after each loading of your website, if the mp3 in total consumes the 1GiB limit then the mp3 video will not work for the rest of the day, until unless the day gets over and the second day's quota gets started.

At last

1. Yes you should look into terms of security.
2. After the limit is reached, it will pose an issue.